# How to cache contents of class files and subsequently include them?

Tags: php, caching

In my web project, there are a huge number of files (class, interface, and trait) which are read by autoloading during the execution time.
The problem is that opening and reading code files (via include_once) takes a lot of time.

It appeared to me that caching the files content and storing all of them into a single file, could speed up the web site.

```
//caching before running the website:

    $cache[$class]=file_get_contents($file);
    .
    .
    .
    file_put_content($cache_path,serialize($cache));


//the beginning:

    $classes=unserialize(file_get_contents($cache_path));


//autoload function:
    ...
    eval('?>'.$classes[$class]);//used eval in place of include_once
    unset($classes[$class]);
...
```

But unfortunately it does not work.

Is there any function that behaves like `include_once` with the difference that it would get ***file content*** rather than ***file path*** (as its argument)?

Answer (score 1):

Look into [OPcache](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.opcache.php), it's going provide the results you want way better than any homebrew optimization you come up with on the scripting side.